# my php codes ain't connecting to mysql database table.what is wrong with my codes?

Tags: php

I want my php file with name getData.php to get data from mysql database table and it's not working?

```
$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='username';
$mysql_password='password';

@mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
@mysqli_select_db("records");

if(!@mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password) )
{
die("CanNot connect to database");  
}
else
{
if(!@mysqli_select_db("student"))
{
echo 'connection successful';
}
else{
die ("CanNot connect to database"); 
}
}
echo "<br />";
$query="SELECT * FROM `info`";
if(@$is_query_run=mysql_query($query))
{
echo"query executed";
while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run))
{
echo $query_execute["Name"];
}
}
else
{
echo "query not executed";
}

?>
```

the name of my database is $records and the target table is named $info the codes connects to the database alright but fails to connect to the table name $info in the $student database.

Comment: Stop suppressing the errors also why are you connecting twice you could just use the `or die(mysqli_error())`. Edited the your question to remove the db information.

Comment: @Script47 Excellent advice. I too am baffled by the hiding of errors; information which could probably answer the question in the first place.

Comment: have u tried  my code?

Comment: i stoped surpressing the errors and this is the error info i got;
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\new\connect.php on line 8

Comment: that part of the codes works perfectly fine but my only problem is with ,
the part of the codes to get information from the database@SugumarVenkatesan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

small mistake interchange die and echo in database selection.

```
$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='username';
$mysql_password='password';
$link = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);


 if(mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
   die("CanNot connect to database");  
 }
 else
 {
    if(!(mysqli_select_db($link, "student")))
    {
        die('cannot connect to the database');
    }
    else{
         echo "connected"; 
     }
  }
 echo "<br />";
 $query="SELECT * FROM `info`";
 if($is_query_run=mysql_query($link,$query))
 {
    echo"query executed";
    while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run))
    {
       echo $query_execute["Name"];
     }
  }
  else
  {
     echo "query not executed";
  }
```

Comment: This still connects twice and suppresses errors which is bad.

Comment: so u mean the the codes should be like:
    $mysql_db = "database name";
    mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_db);

Comment: No, remove all the [`@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) as they stop errors from showing up.

Comment: then what do u mean by i have connect twice?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using MySQLi or PDO.

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("student")) {
    echo "Unable to select student: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM info";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["Name"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

More information and samples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score -1):

The below code solved my issue.

```
$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='username';
$mysql_password='password';
$link = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);


if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("CanNot connect to database");  
}
else
{
    if(!(mysqli_select_db($link, "student")))
    {
        die('cannot connect to the database');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "connected"; 
    }
}
echo "<br />";
$query="SELECT * FROM `info`";
if($is_query_run=mysql_query($link,$query))
{
    echo"query executed";
    while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run))
    {
        echo $query_execute["Name"];
    }
}
else
{
     echo "query not executed";
}
```

Thanks for the code, @v-sugumar